# Unix timestamp with millisecond accuracy is exceeding the maximum value when using the Time crate

Tags: rust, time

I am using the rust time crate.

```
time = { version = "0.3", features = ["macros"] }
```

I have a unix timestamp that has nano second accuracy:

```
1649750400034287729
```

The millisecond equivalent that I caculated is:

```
1649750400034
```

```
#[test]
fn timestam_from_nanos() {
    let ts =
    OffsetDateTime::from_unix_timestamp_nanos(1649750400034287729)
        .unwrap()
        .to_offset(offset!(-4));

    assert_eq!(
        ts.year(), 2022
    );

    assert_eq!(
        ts.month(), time::Month::April
    );
    
    assert_eq!(
        ts.day(), 12
    );

    assert_eq!(
        ts.hour(), 4
    );

    assert_eq!(
        ts.minute(), 0
    );
}
```

The above test works fine.  Now when I try the millisecond level unix timestamp I get this error:

> panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
> ComponentRange { name: "timestamp", minimum: -377705116800, maximum:
> 253402300799, value: 1649750400034, conditional_range: false }'

The value seems to be valid: https://currentmillis.com/?1649750400034

```
#[test]
fn timestam_from_millis() { 
    let ts =
    OffsetDateTime::from_unix_timestamp(1649750400034)
        .unwrap()
        .to_offset(offset!(-4));

    assert_eq!(
        ts.year(), 2022
    );

    assert_eq!(
        ts.month(), time::Month::April
    );
    
    assert_eq!(
        ts.day(), 12
    );

    assert_eq!(
        ts.hour(), 4
    );

    assert_eq!(
        ts.minute(), 0
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try padding the millisecond value with zeros like so `1649750400034000000`. Then you should be able to call `OffsetDateTime::from_unix_timestamp_nanos( 1649750400034000000 )`.

Comment: rust i64 can hold a larger value that that: 1_546_300_800_000_000_000  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff50d47d68c90009542a494916bb52e8

Comment: Hmm, you are correct. It looks like the issue is not in i64 but in "timestamp". I've just looked through the source code for the time crate and the only clue I could find was in `time-main\time\src\offset_date_time.rs:222`. Does that match your stack trace? For convenience here is their repo https://github.com/time-rs/time.

Comment: Yes there is a max value that is set too low it seems?

Comment: I found this question/answer as well that sheds some light on the `253402300799` MAX value in the error message. https://stackapps.com/questions/2699/what-is-the-unix-epoch-date-range-0-253-402-300-799-in-the-api-docs

Comment: what boggles my mind is when I enter 253402300799 into a unix timestamp converter it says the year is 1978 using https://unixtime.org/  Not `Friday, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT`